# Cannot find the declaration of element xml against xsd

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd

I get this error whan trying to validate xml against xsd.
`Cannot find the declaration of element Transactions`.knowing that the element Transactions is exists the XSD.
You find below XML and XSD.
---------------XML--------------------------------

```
<Transactions>
    <User>userId</User>
    <RequestDate>2018-04-04T11:05:16+01:00</RequestDate>
    <Language>en_US</Language>
</Transactions>
```

---------------XSD--------------------------------
    NB:My file contains many xsd like below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="..." xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="imported xsd1" xmlns:ns1="imported xsd1">
      <xs:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="schema5.xsd"/>
      <xs:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="schema4.xsd"/>
      <xs:complexType name="Transactions">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="ns2:...">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="User" type="ns1:User" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="RequestDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Other Element">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ns2:...">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="..." type="ns1:..." minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="..." type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
     </xs:schema>
```

Any help is appreciate,please.

Comment: Nobody can help you without more detail than you've provided.  Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], including the smallest XML and XSD that illustrate the problem.

Comment: Here is a model to follow for asking this type of question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39738095/290085

Comment: That's a lot better, but ideal would be an XSD complete enough to actually validate and reproduce your issue.  From what you've shown, [we can guess...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228021/290085)

Answer (score 0):

Your shown XSD has a type declaration but is lacking an element declaration such as:

```
<xs:element name="Transactions" type="Transactions"/>
```

You may also have to prepend a namespace prefix ahead of `Transactions` in `type="Transactions"` if within an XSD with a target namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response,i have edited my question to be clair.thanks for your help.

Comment: Your XSD *still* has no `Transactions` ***element*** declaration at the top level.

Comment: And your question *still* lacks a [mcve].  Re-read my [**first comment to your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226486/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-xml-against-xsd/52228021?noredirect=1#comment91402453_52226486) and the model I provided you as well.  In that model, the XML and XSD could be validated together by readers.  You've not provided such a MCVE.